# Rank of a map between graded modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, graded-modules

Let $M$ a finitely generated $n$-graded module over the ring of polynomials $k[x_1, .., x_n]$, where $n$-graded means that the indexes of the family are elements of $\mathbb{N}^n$. Let $x^{v-u} : M_u \to M_v$, where $M_u, M_v$ are two homogeneous components, such that if $u=(u_1,.., u_n)$ and $v=(v_1, ..., v_n)$, $u_i \leq v_i $ for every $i$. What exactly is the rank of the map $x^{v-u}$? Any reference?

Comment: This will likely very much depend on $M$, won't it ?

Comment: ...and certainly also on $x^{v-u}$; how is that defined exactly? (The notation is suggestive of something not exactly immediate to formalise)

Comment: @fosco I really don't know, I just found it as it is in a paper, I thought it was standard notation in the context of graded modules. I added to my question some relevant details on the notation though

Comment: $M_u$ is a vector space over $k$, right? So I guess the rank here means the rank in the *usual sense*.

Comment: A module over $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is just a $k$-vector space with $n$ pairwise commuting endomorphisms $T_1,\dots, T_n$; now, a *graded* module requires some condition for the endomorphisms to preserve the grading... and here I stop; my commutative-algebra-fu is too weak.

Comment: @cip Given that condition on $u,v$ I expect $x^{v-u}$ to be the monomial $x_1^{m_1}\dots x_n^{m_n}$ where $m_i := v_1 - u_i \ge 0$ by assumption. So, I believe $x^{v-u}$ is acting as $T_1^{m_1}\dots T_n^{m_n}$ in the sense above, and the assumption on the grading does the rest. Now, what is the rank of this product of matrices certainly depends not only on the $T_i$'s, but also on the respective relations between their kernels and images, taking also into account the fact that they commute with each other.

Comment: (also, what's the reason in not telling us what paper this is from?)

Comment: No reason, except that it is a long paper and it was way easier to make the question specific. Thank you all :)

Comment: Well, no: it's easier to give a precise reference to a specific question. What is the point of being vague? :)